# How to make a clickable datepicker glyphicon-calender icon to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Here are the code for enabling datepicket to work in firefox

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/vendor/modernizr-custom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var datefield=document.createElement("input");
    datefield.setAttribute("type", "date");
    if (datefield.type!=="date"){ //if browser doesn't support input type="date", load files for jQuery UI Date Picker
     document.write('<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/dot-luv/jquery-ui.css " rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />\n');
     document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>\n');

 }       
</script>

<script>
    $(function(){           
        if (!Modernizr.inputtypes.date) { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        // If not native HTML5 support, fallback to jQuery datePicker
            $('input[type=date]').datepicker({
                // Consistent format with the HTML5 picker
                    dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'

                },
                // Localization
                $.datepicker.regional['it']
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Below are the html code

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <label for="inputDate">Date of Birth: </label>
          <div class="input-group datetime">
              <input type="date" id='datefield' name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" required/>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                   </span>

                </div>
            </div>
```

- What I want is when I click on the glyphicon icon/button, that the calendar also appear so that I can choose a date to input into the same field just like the input type=date.

Comment: Change `span` to `label` and use the `for` attribute to the datepicker's id. Check [`HTML#<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: for some reason this works for me on some htmls but on others it doesn't im trying to figure out why it doesn't work on some pages even though i copied the same code and changed the model names

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <label for="inputDate">Date of Birth: </label>
          <div class="input-group datetime">
              <input type="date" id='datefield' name="date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control" required/>
                  <label class="input-group-addon" for="datefield">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                   </label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Change span containing glyphicon-calendar to **label**, add attribute **for** with the ID of parent datetimepicker (in this case ID is ***datefield***), your glyphicon-calendar icon is now clickable and will open the date time picker.

Thanks  @Washington Guedes for original answer

*btw this solution won't work if you nest your date time picker in html table for some reason - thought this info might be useful... you have to use bootstrap.*